# Why does the TableView delegate methods stop working when I add a UITapGestureRecognizer handler method

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UITableViewController with an xib that is being used in a popover. It was working fine until I tried to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to the view. With the tableview wired to the UITapGestureRecognizer as an outlet collection, when the user taps an item in the table, the tap handler fires but the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method of the tableview no longer fires.

What I am trying to do is get the position of the tap so I can throw the next popover up in a reasonable location. Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Heres is what my tableview wiring looks like...

[image]

Here is the wiring for the recognizer...

[image]

Here is my tap handler, which when wired up, fires fine when the user selects an item.

```
- (IBAction)tapHandler:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        tapPosition = [sender locationInView:self.view];
    }
}
```

Here is the didselectrowAtIndexPath method. Fires fine unless I wire up the tapGestureRecognizer...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   [myPO dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
   [self.delegate popupListItemSelected:self withItemRow:indexPath.row item:[listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Here is the applicable part of my interface file. All of the objects are synthesized...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol PopUpListViewControllerDelegate;

@interface PopUpListViewController : UITableViewController {
   id<PopUpListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
   IBOutlet UITableView *poupListTableView;
   UIPopoverController *myPO;
   NSMutableArray *listItems;
   IBOutlet UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;   
}
@property (assign) id<PopUpListViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *poupListTableView;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *listItems;

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
- (IBAction)tapHandler:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
- (CGPoint)getTappedPosition;

@end
```

Comment: The tap gesture recognizer is eating the taps intended for the table view. How were you expecting this to work? You can't have your cake and eat it too...

Comment: Ok. So I can't get the tap position in this manner. Here's the basic issue. You can presentPopoverFromRect or presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem but If you are throwing up another popover from a selected item in a popover, how do you present the new popover at a position close to where the user tapped?

Comment: You aren't supposed to put up two popovers simultaneously so the problem doesn't arise. The usual thing when the user taps a table row of a popover is to push a new view onto the navigation controller (inside the same popover).

Comment: I see your other answer and will try to work with what you suggested, but in referencd to your comment here, I am not trying to put 2 popovers up at the same time. The user gets a popover and based on what they select that popover closes and another popover is presented, contents of which are based on what they selected in the first popover. Oh! I see what you are saying... use the same popover. Interesting, but it might be difficult as the data for the second popover is being retrieved from a URL request to a web server. Going to give that a try.

Comment: Mark, thank you for setting me straight. Reloading the popover works great! Please post your suggestion as an answer to my question so I can mark it as answered. The answer you posted I am sure would have worked as well but reloading works so much better.

Comment: Matt and Mark. Your names are so much alike, I got you confused as one person. Mark, thanks for your suggestion, and like I said I am sure it would have worked, but I think Matt's comment reflects the correct way to do it. I did vote your answer up. Again for Matt if you could rephrase you comment as an answer I will mark this question as answered.

Comment: Going from a tap on a row to a detail view using a push via the navigation controller is more of an Apple UI standard.  So, good to prefer Matt's approach.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to use the CGPoint from your tap handler and find the corresponding row using the UITableView method:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```

So, everything could potentially be handled by your tapHandler:  (warning! untested pseudo-code!)

```
- (IBAction)tapHandler:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        tapPosition = [sender locationInView:self.view];

        // use the appropriate name for your tableView, of course.
        CGPoint pointInTable = [sender locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:pointInTable];

       [myPO dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
       [self.delegate popupListItemSelected:self withItemRow:indexPath.row item:[listItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    }
}
```